# Contains always returns false

Tags: java, lambda, set, contains

I'm writing chess game and I got trouble with checking if move is valid.

Long story short, I got Pawn (extends Piece) class that has

```
 //First element of array represents row, second element of array represents column
 Set<int[]> legalMoves = new HashSet<>();

 void initLegalMoves() {
    if(color == PieceColor.WHITE) {
        legalMoves.add(new int[] {-1, 0});
    } else {
        legalMoves.add(new int[] {1, 0});
    }
 }
```

Now I got another class `MoveValidator` that checks, obviously, if the move is valid.

```
    private boolean isLegalMove(int oldRow, int oldColumn, int newRow, int newColumn){
        int rowDifference = newRow - oldRow;
        int columnDifference = newColumn - oldColumn;

        board.getSelectedTile().getPiece().getLegalMoves().forEach(x -> {
            if(x[0] == rowDifference && x[1] == columnDifference){
                System.out.println("Ok move");
            }
        });
        return board.getSelectedTile().getPiece().getLegalMoves().contains(new int[] {rowDifference, columnDifference});
    }
```

Although it doesnt seem to work, return value is always false. Rest of the code seems relevant, `forEach` I'v put before prints "Ok move" when move is indeed ok. I could probably achieve what I want with some `Iterator` and `for loops`, but why do `contains` always returns false? Do I need to override `equals()` for class I want to check like that? Can't do that for an `int[]` tho, right? 
On the other hand, I could just use lambda and `forEach` like I did to print value. Still, I can't simply put `return true` inside that `if statement`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Set<int[]>`, instead use `Set<Set<Integer>>` because array doesn't implement `equals` and `hashCode` method and that's why `contains` won't work and that's why it returns `false`.

One option is iterate through the `Set<int[]>` and compare each element by `Arrays.equals()` method.

Or just use `Set<Set>` because `Set` implements `equals` and `hashCode` and you'll be able to use `contains` method

Comment: `for(int[] legalMoves :  board.getSelectedTile().getPiece().getLegalMoves()) {
            if(Arrays.equals(legalMoves, new int[] {rowDifference, columnDifference})) {
                return true;
            }
        }` worked, thanks